# Upgrading Old Hp Proliant DL180 Processor G1

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fsb

Can i update the **HP Proliant DL180 Generation 1** Processor with:

Intel Xeon E5405 (12M Cache, 2.00 GHz, 1333 MHz FSB) or

Intel® Xeon® Processor 5130 (4M Cache, 2.00 GHz, 1333 MHz FSB)

Is it *possible* and **save** to use different size of FSB for Processor/Motherboard? My motherboard has 1066 FSB but those processors have bigger FSB value?

Comment: What processors support your motherboard? You should check the list of the manufacturer. Typically newer processors will be supported by BIOS updates.

Comment: That is the problem, i couldn't find any documentation for the Generation 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processor FSB can't have a higher frequency than motherboard's FSB. You should check for a BIOS update to see if your motherboard supports that FSB frequency.

If that's not possible, you'll have to "underclock" your processor.

Read more about FSB on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-side_bus#Related_component_speeds).

Comment: What might happen? Could it damage the motherboard/processor? Thanks.

Comment: @user2577399 It won't boot or if it does the system will hang frequently. It could potentially destroy your motherboard.

Comment: It wouldn't just not boot it wouldn't even POST...